# How to convert Ripple Current spec to ESR?

Tags: capacitor, datasheet, esr, ripple-current

It used to be that vendors like Digikey gave a cap's ESR value and not ripple current. Nowadays, it seems more report only ripple current and not ESR. What gives with that?

So what are we supposed to do with "ripple current" if we want to know ESR?  Many datasheets are not reporting ESR any longer. If a 4.7µF/250v electrolytic cap listed "Ripple Current = 146.2mA @ 10kHz", can we derive an ESR from that?

I see where [ESR can be derived from the Dissipation Factor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/358536/unrealistic-esr-calculated-from-df)... but DF isn't reported for this cap either. Ideas?

Comment: Get a cap with a decent spec is my advice.

Comment: I agree with @Andyaka.  You might get a very rough estimate by figuring that the thermal rise due to the ripple current spec at max ambient gives the max rated temperature, but wait, that's probably not spec'd either.  You can try the manufacturer's website instead of Digi-Key, but if you can't find what you need there then choose a cap with better specs.